# how to find users roles stored using bitwise technique in sql?

Tags: sql, bit-manipulation, roles

I would like to run a simple query to get all users of a particular role, the problem is user roles are stored in bitwise numbers using power of 2 pattern.

For example the roles table is.

```
1      role one
2      role two...
4
8
16
```

In a user table we have

```
username  other columns   roles
  billy       ....        192949
```

I'm not sure how to query for a role like that...

Comment: 1) What flavor of SQL 2) Can you change how these are stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single role:

```
DECLARE @RoleOne = 1

SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE (roles & @RoleOne) > 0
```

Or a member of all multiple roles

```
DECLARE @MultipleRoles = 1 + 4 + 64

SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE (roles & @MultipleRoles) = @MultipleRoles
```

(I'm assuming SQL Server but will be very similar for other flavours)